# Update user claims on site if claims changed on my identity server's database

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, jwt, asp.net-identity, identity

I have a couple of sites that require a logged user with specific permissions like role, group. So i decided to create my own identity server with the user's database. I used JWt-token and cookie auth to achieve my goal. When a not-logged-in user tries to get access to any of my sites, the site redirects him to the identity server's login page. After successful login, the server generates JWT token with the user's claims

```
private async Task<string> CreateAccessToken(User user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
            };

            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
                var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(userRole);
                if (role != null)
                {
                    var roleClaims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
                    foreach (Claim roleClaim in roleClaims)
                    {
                        claims.Add(roleClaim);
                    }
                }
            }

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: AuthOptions.ISSUER,
                    audience: AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4)),
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
            var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

            return encodedJwt;

        }
```

which will be extracted and stored in the cookie file on client PC to work with site's resources.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TokenForCookie(string token)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("accesstoken", token);
            var JWThandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var validations = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
            };

            SecurityToken tokenSecure;
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

            try
            {
                claimsPrincipal = JWThandler.ValidateToken(token, validations, out tokenSecure);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                return new JsonResult(new { success = false, message = "Token validation error" });
            }

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal,
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true,
        AllowRefresh = true
    });

            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }
```

This works fine for me, but the only problem is: how can i update user's claims if the identity server's admins changed them or if they changed manually in the database?

I googled some articles and seems like i need to create some validator added to each request for comparing claims between resources sites and identity server. I am new to the asp.net core and identity process so i spent more than a week building at least something like that. If you know a better way how this can be done, please help me to find the right way

Comment: Do you mean when user browser already has old cookie, then admin changed roles of this user , so this user should unlock new permission. But user's cookie is old so he cannot access, you want to update the cookie claims to new one automatically?  Does the "user" information(roles etc) in "CreateAccessToken(User user)" come from a database after login with only username and password?

Comment: @Jerry Something like that, yes. I need to update user's permission without manual re-login. And yes, the "user" information(roles etc) in "CreateAccessToken(User user)" comes from a database. This is an identity server side method that generates JWT-token. So now somehow i need to check if those claims are valid from other sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is general solution for api scenario, which is refresh token.
When user login, he get access token & refresh token.

The access token with user principals exipred in a shorter time such as 1 day. This prevents the old principals(roles) keeps being effective. When access token expired, you can get a new access token just using the refresh token. thus you don't have to login again to get access token, the refresh token authenticate for you.

refresh token has longer expire time such as months, but it doesn't contain any information of user principals(roles). It is just used for getting new access token which contains user principals(roles).
Refresh token is simply generated , just a random code:

```
        private static string GenerateRefreshToken()
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[64];
            using var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
            rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
        }
```

For how refresh token work,you can try this tutorial with codes can be downloaded.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens-in-net-6-0/

Your project used cookie so you should make the cookie expired more quickly. Then use refresh token to get access token by each request ,or use javascript timer to make this request at background every day to make an update.

Comment: I have read about refresh tokens, thanks. But i still do not completely understand this topic. 
1) Which is the best way to store those tokens? js localStorage\sessionStorage are not safe bcs any js code can access them, right? In my current solution claims from jwt extract and store into the cookie. So should i save refresh-token in another cookie?

Comment: 2) Which way should i use refresh-token in my apps? For example, user got tokens after logging in auth server. Token with claims will be saved in a cookie with the token's expiration date. Then i need to create middleware that checks the token's expiration date. And, if true, automatically send a request to the auth server with the refresh token. This refresh token will be compared with the token from the user's database. If they are the same, the server will recreate new tokens and then send them back. If not, the server will return some error and the user must be relogin